# Error int too large to convert to float en Python

Tags: python, lista

Tengo un código en Python en donde se debe de generar x cantidad de números aleatorios, los cuales quiero adjuntar en una clase con dos valores, `x` que es su posición y `fmay` que es una operación que se realiza con el número generado aleatoriamente. Si embargo, al momento de compilarlo, en la línea `fmay = (math.exp(dias*-1) * (dias**i))/math.factorial(i)`, que es en donde se realiza dicha operación, me genera el error `int too large to convert to float`. Antes usé un for, en donde no me generó dicho error, pero lo descarté ya que un while me servía más para lo que necesitaba. Cualquier sugerencia o duda es bienvenida. Adjuntaré el código completo.

```
import math
import random

class Array: 
    def __init__(self, x,fmin,fmay):
        self.x = x
        self.fmin = fmin
        self.fmay =  fmay

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{:f} : {:f} : {:f}'.format(self.x, self.fmin, self.fmay)

main_array = []

dias = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de días:\n"))
dias = round(dias)
if 0>=dias:
    while True:
        dias = int(input("Ingrese un valor válido:\n"))
        dias = round(dias)
        if 0<dias:
            break

count=0
dingdong=0
i=0

while verif==0:
        x = round(count)
        fmin = random.uniform(0,1)
        fmay = (math.exp(dias*-1) * (dias**i))/math.factorial(i)
        count=count+1
        main_array.append(Array(x,fmin,fmay)) 
        i=i+1
        if fmay >= 0.999:
            verif = 1

numal = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de números aleatorios:\n"))
numal = round(numal)
if 0>=numal:
    while True:
        numal = int(input("Ingrese un valor válido:\n"))
        numal = round(numal)
        if 0<numal:
            break

total=0

print(main_array)

for i in range(0, len(main_array)-1):
    if i>=numal:
        break
    num = random.uniform(0,1)
    print(num)
    for j in range(0, len(main_array)-1):
        if num>main_array[j].fmay and num<=main_array[j+1].fmay:
            #print(coord.fmay)
            #print(main_array[j-1].fmay)
            total=total+main_array[j].x
            print(total)

print("XTotal " + str(total) + "\n")
```

Comment: intente con `from decimal import Decimal`  y luego hacer un `Decimal(math.factorial(i))`

Comment: En python los enteros no tienen límite de tamaño. Pueden crecer tanto como se necesite. En cambio los flotantes, al estar codificados según un estándar de 64 bits, sí que tienen un tamaño máximo. Si mezclas ambos tipos sin cuidado, puede ser que alguna operación necesite convertir implícitamente un entero a flotante para poder hacerse, y será en ese momento cuando falle si el entero es demasiado grande. `math.factorial()`  te retorna enteros, así que por ahi no hay problema. Pero cuando lo juntas con `math.exp()` es cuando aparece el problema.

Comment: Mejor que convertir `math.factorial(i)`, usa `Decimal.exp()`: `fmay = (Decimal.exp(-dias) * (dias**i)) / math.factorial(i)`. La operación usará datos _decimal_, que puedes convertir luego a _float_ si es necesario: `float(fmay)`

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por aclarar mis dudas de una manera constructiva. Aprecio mucho su tiempo y paciencia, sus respuestas me sirvieron bastante.

Answer (score 1):

La razón inmediata del error es que la variable `i` crece sin parar, y el código falla al tratar de calcular factorial(171).

Sin saber que hace el código, no se puede decir si opera correctamente o no, o cómo debería operar, pero en si o si hay que salir del ciclo cuando `i` llega a 171.

Refactorizando el código podemos eliminar la variable `i` y dejar sólo `count`. Si te das cuenta, ambas avanzan a la par.

No necesito redondear `count`, pues es un entero.

Tampoco necesito `verif`; en su lugar chequeo la condición directamente en el `while`.

Reordenando las expresiones, el código se reduce a esto:

```
count=0
fmay = 1

while fmay >= 0.999 or i > 170:
        fmin = random.uniform(0,1)
        fmay = (math.exp(dias*-1) * (dias**count))/math.factorial(count)
        count += 1
        
        main_array.append(Array(count, fmin, fmay))
```

Probado da resultados, que podrían ser correctos.

```
Ingrese la cantidad de días:
10
Ingrese la cantidad de números aleatorios:
20
[1.000000 : 0.213507 : 0.000045]
XTotal 0


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Lo apliqué con algunos cambios personales y funciona perfectamente bien. Muchas gracias.